# What is the best tactic for battling wretches in Gears of War?

Tags: gears-of-war

I'm currently playing through Gears of War on hardcore mode and I'm having real trouble dispatching wretches, which are also called grubs by the Gears.

I've tried aiming at them properly, hand to hand combat, and just firing wildly when they get close, but I can't find a way to beat them consistently and more often than not will end up dying and having to try again from the last checkpoint.

Do they have any particular weaknesses that I am missing? Can anyone offer any advise on how best to deal with them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best strategy when dealing with the normal wretches is to use the shotgun. Don't aim (so shoot from the hip) and then melee when they get closer to you. If they get too close you can always shoot the shotgun then roll backwards to give yourself some distance.

With the Lambent wretches, the explosion you see when they die also effects other locust. So, if possible, try and get a lambent wretch to explode next to other enemies. Two birds with one stone :-)

If a lambent wretch gets too close to you, melee and roll backwards. Or shoot and roll backwards (as you've probably found out, the explosion hurts.....a lot!!)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I usually grab a sniper rifle in preference to the shotgun, but I'll try this out. I didn't realise that the explosions damaged the enemies as well so I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: I agree. My biggest problem with the wretches was the fact that I would have my lancer equipped through the majority of the game. They come at you so quick that aiming can be tricky. And using melee can be dicey too. You have to already have your chainsaw revved before they get to you, otherwise you'll probably keep getting hit. And they usually run in groups, so if you do get one with the chainsaw, you might end up getting hit by the second or third. shotgun is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer hip fire with the gnasher. I like it most due to the fact its most likely to hit them it deals a lot of damage and on gears of war 1 on insane it was most safe and efficient

Comment: Why do you prefer this method?  Please provide more information about why this is preferable over other methods.